# how to make the actual application/widget?

Tags: flash, widget, clock

I have made an analog clock in adobe flash CS5 and want to make it a proper application.
When i create an exe file it will run in flash player or firefox etc., which i dont want.
Visual Basic 8 could not help me either.

So my question is: **How do i make a real, self running and self installing application for
this flash clock?**

There are hundreds of clocks to download on the net, which run on there own and do not open
in flash player. How is this done?
It would be great, if You could give me some hints
Best regards
Tom

Answer (score 0):

if i corectly undestood what you need, then it is the Adobe AIR application. which will export for you the .air file, and you can deploy it as a self installing application on win/os/linux.

simply open the file, and in the Profile properties chage it to Adobe Air, but not AS3.